# DigitalOcean A records and CNAMEs not propogating?

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, namecheap

I am having some issues with DigitalOcean A records and CNAMEs. An A record for `www.schoolproject.me` was created, and DO would not let me make one for just `schoolproject.me` (do I need to make one for `@.schoolproject.me` instead?).

When checking both of those domain names for A records on either MXToolbox or a propagation checker, neither of them provide any response whatsoever. For subdomains of this, I have CNAMEs done in DO as well (this is an Evilginx project, so ones for `api.twitter.com.schoolproject.me`, `abs.twitter.com.schoolproject.me`, and `twitter.com.schoolproject.me`) which also don't have CNAMEs in MXToolbox.

The nameservers were set up in Namecheap, as `nsX.schoolproject.me` - 1-3 as X that point to the IP of the DO droplet, as suggested in Evilginx setup guides.

The question is, why aren't these A records and CNAMEs showing up in any tool? When Evilginx attempts to get SSL certs from LetsEncrypt I am met with this -

```
[abs.twitter.com.schoolproject.me] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for abs.twitter.com.schoolproject.me - check that a DNS record exists for this domain, url:
[api.twitter.com.schoolproject.me] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for api.twitter.com.schoolproject.me - check that a DNS record exists for this domain, url:
[twitter.com.schoolproject.me] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for twitter.com.schoolproject.me - check that a DNS record exists for this domain, url:
```

...which is the big issue I'm having, but the simple way to check this is to just drop it into MXToolbox online and it does the same thing.

Thanks in advance. I've done some easier DNS stuff before, but this is a bit over what I have done prior.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but do understand that DNS propagation is a myth, this just doesn't exist. If you query authoritative nameservers you see changes immediately and this is the first thing to check, and only after recursive servers. And `@.schoolproject.me` makes no sense, `@` in a "zonefile" denotes origin aka the zone name itself, but all depends on your provider UI/API, you need to ask it directly. See https://dnsviz.net/d/www.schoolproject.me/YZQGIA/servers/ ; the authoritative nameservers are dns1/dns2.registrar-servers.com not what you quote.

Comment: Considering I saw other posts related to DO and DNS on here, I thought it was alright. You were right though, it just got solved as Namecheap was having issues with the custom nameservers. I'll answer this question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. In Namecheap, make sure to add your nameservers you made under Advanced DNS settings to the Custom Nameserver section of the site. Ugh. That was too easy.